# integrate zxing in own android app

Tags: java, android, zxing

Hi I'm a beginner in android. I want to write an android app which has the zxing barcode scanner integrated. I used this website to integrate the function:

http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/

everything works well, but if I say that I want to open the app with my scanner, the app crashes.

if I use the installed barcode scanner everything works...

LogCat says:

```
04-28 19:05:53.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11666): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 19:05:53.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11666): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-28 19:05:53.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11666):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-28 19:05:53.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11666):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
04-28 19:05:53.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11666):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
04-28 19:05:53.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11666):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1984)
04-28 19:05:53.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11666):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
04-28 19:05:53.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11666):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
04-28 19:05:53.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11666):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
04-28 19:05:53.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11666):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-28 19:05:53.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11666):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-28 19:05:53.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11666):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
04-28 19:05:53.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11666):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 19:05:53.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11666):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-28 19:05:53.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11666):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
04-28 19:05:53.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11666):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
04-28 19:05:53.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11666):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-28 19:05:53.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11666): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.zxing.ResultMetadataType
04-28 19:05:53.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11666):    at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.<clinit>(CaptureActivity.java:101)
04-28 19:05:53.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11666):    ... 15 more
```

Comment: Please post the LogCat output

Comment: If you are "a beginner in android", you should be doing something *much* simpler than this, particularly since what you are doing (integrating ZXing directly rather than using the Barcode Scanner app and `IntentIntegrator`) is not recommended by the ZXing authors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions in the blog post are incorrect, in at least one area.

The following paragraph from Step #3:

> The project will not currently build. We need to add the core.jar file (that we produced in the previous step) into our project. Right-click on ZXing project –> properties –> Java Build Path –> Add External Jars –> Navigate to and select core.jar –> Open –> OK.

should read:

> The project will not currently build. We need to add the `core.jar` file (that we produced in the previous step) into our project. Simply copy it into the ZXing project's `libs/` directory.

Please undo the manual changes you presumably made based on the original paragraph, and copy the `core.jar` file into the ZXing project's `libs/` directory.